# Uncaught Error Error: Cannot find module 'express'

Tags: node.js, discord.js

im trying to make a discord bot using discord.js it works but whenever i try hosting it i get
(Uncaught Error Error: Cannot find module 'express') my friend told me it should work
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CouiG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go your command line and type `npm install express`. This is how you install required modules.

Comment: thank you im so dumb!! i thought i had it but i reset my pc so i forgot.